# How to add Jsp page in Jhipster app

Tags: jhipster

I am working on Jhipster project.

I am trying to add and run .jsp page in my current jHipster project but its not working.

How to add and run server side page like '.jsp' extensiion page in jHipster project?

Please let me know as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

With JHipster, you are supposed to use Thymeleaf, not JSPs, for your server-side pages.
If you still wish to use a JSP, thus, it's just a normal web application, running on Tomcat, so it should work out of the box: can you describe your bug more precisely? Something more than "it's not working"?

Comment: Can we combine spring DispatcherServlet with InternalResourceViewResolver to solve this problem. I also thought of combining view technologies like JSP into hipster project. Will surely give it a try to prove that it may work.

Comment: Yes it's sure it can work, JSPs just work out of the box on Tomcat/Jetty, and there isn't anything specific that forbids you from using them. Then again, the goal of the project is to use AngularJS, so it's a very different approach.

Comment: Agree..With AngularJS we are targeting mostly for single page application with RESTful backend and rely mostly on static HTML templates. Mentioned problem can arise when system is being migrated from legacy to new system with upgraded technologies. User may redirect to old jsp based app from angular page.